# Is $x^4 + y^2 + z^6 = 0$ a subspace of $R^3$?

Tags: vector-spaces

I have already verified it contains the zero vector, and gone through the standard showing that $\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2 \in S$, however I can't help but think there's a counterexample, because surely the even powers ensure that the inverse of any element in S is equal to the element, violating the inverse axiom? Unless it's true the only vector in S is the zero vector.

Just need a little clarification here.

Comment: What are the real solutions of $x^4=0?$ And of $y^2=0?$ And of $z^6=0?$

Comment: What does mean $x^4 + y^2 + z^6 = 0$?

Comment: @mfl 0 for all of them. I'm guessing this implies S only contains the 0 vector, but could you explain why? I don't believe I have covered this (probably very simple) concept yet.

Comment: @Piquito Is it as simple as the sum of 3 terms, all strictly positive = 0 iff each of the terms = 0?

Answer (score 1):

The only element of your space is the origin. Therefore it is a vector sub-space of $\mathbb{R}^3$.